# Continue SSH background task/jobs when closing SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, tasks, nohup

I have the same question as [here](https://superuser.com/questions/388102/close-ssh-connection) but even beyond that.

If I logout/exit the SSH connection, I need my program running in background.
Before exit, I type `bg` and `jobs` to check background running task, but after exiting SSH, the program doesn't run, it closes when I close the SSH window.

What can I do if I want my program still running after closing the SSH window?  I do use `nohup` `screen` but it also doesn't work, or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't put your answer into the question. Post it as an answer below once you can (in about 7 hours) using the **Answer your question** button. Thank you. (Also note that there's no need to add `<br/>`s to your post. Just make paragraphs as needed. And while you're at it, please use proper capitalization. It makes your posts easier to read.)

Comment: BTW no need to use `bg` or `nohup` when using `screen`. Also [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/631759/remote-sharing-of-a-terminal/631764) is related.

Comment: you make check this thread @ stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client

Answer (score 65, accepted):

When you use `screen` you need to *detach* with <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> before you exit `ssh`.

Alternatively, if you want to run a process directly with screen you can use

```
screen -dmSL [session name] [commands]
```

- `-d` starts a screen session and immediately detaches from it
- `-m` forces creating a new screen session
- `-S` lets you give the session a name
- `-L` turns on logging to `~/screenlog.0`

**example:**

```
screen -dmSL workstuff myscript.sh
```

You can then either:

**resume later using** `screen -x workstuff`

or

**check the log file** `less -r ~/screenlog.0`

Answer (score 17):

Use `tmux`. I'm not even sure if `screen` is even still under active development. It's kind of a preference thing, but as someone who uses `tmux`, I can testify that it set up in about 5 minutes, and worked perfectly.

On a Debian-based system (on the remote machine):

`sudo apt-get install tmux`

then enter `tmux` to enter, run whatever process you need, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> then <kbd>D</kbd> (this leaves the tmux session). Then, you can log out of SSH.

When you need to come back/check on it again, start up SSH, and enter `tmux attach`. It will take you back to your `tmux` session.

`tmux` has many more capabilities, as detailed here. But, this should solve your immediate problem.

Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

At last, I solved it using `screen`:

In screen mode, detach it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. Then you can close the SSH window.

Answer (score 6):

nohup use:
The first of the commands below starts the program abcd in the background in such a way that the subsequent logout does not stop it.

> $ nohup abcd &
>
> $ exit